# #memurai - What are the AV exclusions

Tags: memurai

I have a install of memurai however feel my AV impacting it, I can find the redis list but noting  for memurai. the impact seem that we lose connection to the cashed db

found the Redis settings but not able to find the memurai.
Path    Description
"/opt/redislabs",   Main installation directory for all Redis Enterprise Software binaries. "/opt/redislabs/bin",   Binaries for all the utilities for command line access and managements such. as “rladmin” or “redis-cli”.
"/opt/redislabs/config",    System configuration files. /opt/redislabs/lib  System library files. "/opt/redislabs/sbin",    System binaries for tweaking provisioning.`

not sure if this is the same for memurai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default installation settings are detailed here: https://docs.memurai.com/en/installation.html

The (default) folder you should exclude is "C:\Program Files\Memurai"; you might need to exclude binaries separately; you could exclude all 4 executables in that folder or at least "memurai.exe".